# Force delete a Google Glass GDK Glassware App

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I loaded one of the sample GDK apps and ran it on glass using ADT. How do I now delete the App from glass?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can uninstall it using `adb` from the terminal:

```
$ adb uninstall your.apps.package.name
```

where `your.apps.package.name` is the package defined in the application's manifest.

Furthermore, if you ever install anything where you don't have the source and you're not sure what the package name is, you can list all the installed packages with the following command:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages
```

Comment: Tony its possible from adb but if we want to uninstall the application from code what have to use? Native android uninstall approach is not possible cause in dialog we can't navigate button to button. So what we should follow for uninstalling from code?

Answer (score 2):

You may find Chrome "app"   ChromeADB useful too.  This is a visual interface for simple use.

See
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeadb/fhdoijgfljahinnpbolfdimpcfoicmnm/reviews?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher